# Launch minimized Konsole from Dolphin (KDE)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

On Kubuntu 18.04 I was able to launch the "konsole" minimized using a Dolphin ServiceMenus with:

`kstart --iconify konsole --separate --workdir %f -e ...`

On the new Kubuntu 20.04 however "kstart" doesn't seem to exist anymore and there's only "kstart5" that returns me an error message:

> Unknown options: separate, workdir.

I tried to look at the "--help" and did a few random attempts but without luck, does anyone know how to pass correctly the command with the various options in this version? or how to start from the Dolphin ActionMenu a minimized Konsole with options?

This is my .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
Name=apri1caso.desktop
Icon=folder-videos-symbolic
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin,inode/directory
Actions=apri1caso;

[Desktop Action apri1caso]
Name=Apri Video a caso
GenericName=Random Video
Icon=folder-videos-symbolic
Exec=kstart5 --iconify konsole --separate --workdir %f -e sh /opt/Project/Script/random.sh
```

Comment: Do you need `kstart5` only because you want `konsole` iconified? Does your `Exec=` work fine except for konsole not being iconified? And do you need `%f` or `%U`? Incidentally, `kstart5` is present in Kubuntu 18.04 as well.

Comment: Yes, I use `kstart` only to start `konsole` iconified so I don't have to do it by hand every time.
Yes, my `Exec=` works properly if I omit `kstart5 --iconify`.
I need the `%f` (I think), with the old version worked properly with that variable.
Yes, I saw now on a VM that `kstart5` was also present in 18.04 and gives me the same problem, which does not make `kstart` (on 18.04).